# What are the mantras that can be chanted without initiation for a householder?

Tags: mantras

What are some advices for a householder who wants great knowledge and intelligence in various fields of study in this world? Note , the mantras should be the ones which will not cause any bad after effect as we are not initiated by a proper guru. Hence , I wanted to know what are some of the mantras which any common householder can chant daily?

**Note:** is the mantra “om batukbhairavay namaha” and “ Om Hreem Batukaya Apadudharanaya Kuru Kuru Batukaya Hreem Om” , shiva mahimna strotam and gaytri mantra safe to chant without any initiation from guru?

Comment: Chanting a mantra requires laya and breathwork (beejamantras you are writing) in proper accents. Just like you cannot learn a song just from lyrics, you cannot make any sense out of Beeja mantras. All mantras are safe because they won't work without someone else charging it for you, nor proper accent and laya. Only bhakti mantras can work without any initiation, not tantric ones.

Comment: Please @User29449 can you name some Bhakti mantras of shiva, Bhairava, Durga and Ganesha which I can recite?

Comment: *Om Namah Shivaya*, *Om namo bhagavate vasudhevaya namah*, etc are all bhakti mantras. It's always good to start with 108 names, stotra, etc because they always respond faster than these mantras.

Comment: Can you name some strotas for batuka bhairava which I can chant daily @User29449

Comment: I don't know any in particular, but on Googling, I found a few: https://www.astromantra.com/batuk-bhairav-stotra/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sri Shiva Purana 7.2.26.:

> 8. Whether bound or free, if the devotee worships with the five-syllabled mantra he is liberated. No doubt need be entertained in this respect.
> 9. Whether a man is a follower of Rudra or not, whether he is fallen or deluded if he worships but once with Rudra Sūkta he is liberated.
> 10. **A devotee of Śiva who has conquered anger, whether he has or has not secured initiation grace from the preceptor shall worship the lord with the Sūktamantra or the six-syllabled mantra (om nama sivaya).**
> 11. **Surely the former is better than the latter. He becomes liberated and absorbed into Brahman.**
> 12. Hence one shall always worship Śiva with devotion repeating the mantras, once, twice or thrice or always.

I hope this helps. Prd..